# Proof of Wright’s path-tracing rules

Tags: covariance, structural-equation-modeling, partial-correlation

I have a path diagram.
[image]
According to Wright’s path-tracing rules, correlation of B & D = b + a*f.
However, when I tried to proof the above result by solving

```
cov(B, D) = cov(fA + gC, aA + bB)
```

I didn't get the same result with Wright’s rule.
It seems the problem originated from using *B = fA + gC* instead of *B = fA*. But I thought *B = fA + gC* would be correct because variable B is actually affected by both A and C.
Even when I applied *B = fA*,

```
cov(B, D) = cov(fA, aA + bB)
 = cov(fA, aA) + cov(fA, bB)
 = fa*1 + fb*cov(A, B)
 = fa * (f^2)*b
```

Can anyone tells me what I've got wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought B = fA + gC would be correct because variable B is actually affected by both A and C

No, nothing is pointing to B, so nothing "affects" it.  In a path diagram, a variable('s variance) is the sum of (the variance of) everything that directly points to it (including residuals; see below).  Double-headed arrows are not directed paths; they represent (co)variances.

The `b` path is a *partial* regression slope (i.e., slope of B's residual predicting D's residual, after A is partialled out of both B and D). So the reason that  `fa` must be added to `b` is that B--D's zero-order correlation (i.e., **all** variance in common between B and D) includes both their partial correlation (`b`) *and* the correlation of D with **the part of B that is in common with A** (i.e., `fa`).

Here is the correct linear/covariance algebra corresponding to the path diagram:

```
cov(B, D) = cov(B, aA   + bB + i)
          = cov(B, aA)  + cov(B, bB)  + cov(B, i)
          = a*cov(B, A) + b*var(B)    + 0
          = a*f         + b*1 (because all are standardized)
          = af + b
```

[Loehlin's (2004) SEM book](https://doi.org/10.4324/9781410609823) is freely available at [this site](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Earnabc/discrete/loehlin.pdf), if that helps.